# How to make an output of a column that "filters" through another?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Essentially, I have a Column A with a bunch of websites, and Column B with a bunch of acceptable websites. I'd like column C to display the websites from Column A, except those that **contain** url's from column B.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexmatch()` as long as the text strings in column `B` do not contain [regex special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping), like this:

`=filter( A2:A, not( regexmatch( A2:A, textjoin("|", true, B2:B) ) ) )`